# android status turns semi-transparent when android:windowTranslucentStatus is true

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my Android APP has its status bar translucent. However, when I set like this:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

My status bar turns to be semi-transparent with a black color:
[image]

But what I really want is that the status bar has the same color with my APP, just like this:
[image]

I want to know what's wrong with my APP?
My device is Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

It's default behaviour for Android API Level 20+
If you want use completely transparent status bar you should set transparent status bar color:
@android:color/transparent

Your second screenshot with shadow in status bar taken on API Level 19 or less.